# How to execute an application built with Framework 2 and run with 3.5.1 using TLS 1.2 without rebuilding the app

Tags: .net, ssl, .net-2.0, tls1.2

Scenario:

we must run a 3rd party application built with `.Net Framework 2` on a `Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter SP1 Build 7601` server with only `TLS 1.2` enabled and `.Net 3.5.1` and `.Net 4.7.1` installed.

TLS registry changes explained here have been done:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn786418(v=ws.11)#BKMK_SchannelTR_TLS12

Trying to execute the patch available here has been done:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154518/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework

We get in the MSU logs a

> There is no update bundle to install

and the execution ends with

> The update is not applicable to your computer

If we try to connect a Framework 2 client to a Framework 2 server with SSL without specifying the protocol it always uses TLS1, if we disable the protocol then it fails with an exception about not being able to find a compatible protocol.

Comment: What service pack do you have installed on your server?

Comment: @virusstorm: SP1 Build 7601. Updated the question too.